# Makefile: wait for a file to become available

Tags: multithreading, makefile

I have a big and complicated makefiles structure I need to work with. At some point in one of the makefiles, a header file is needed in a specific dir. Sometimes make breaks, because that file does not exist (yet). This happens since the make is called with `-j8` and there is a race condition between different make files. What is the best way to sync in here? Is it possible for example, within the make language, to check whether a file exists every 1 second and only fail on timeout or continue once it appears?

Comment: Problems such as this are almost always due to incomplete dependency specification.  You need to tell `make` how to create/update the problematic file.

Comment: https://accu.org/journals/overload/14/71/miller_2004/ discusses some approaches. I don't agree with half of it, but it's probably worth a read nevertheless.

Comment: The short and direct answer to your question is "no" there's no way to have make wait for a prerequisite to appear using the makefile syntax.  The design of make, as mentioned in the previous comments, is that if you need need a file to exist before running a recipe, then you list it as a prerequisite of the target and the recipe for it should build it.  I suppose of course you could always have the recipe wait for it to appear, instead: that would be strange but would work.  You have to use the shell (in a recipe) to do it though, not makefile syntax.

Comment: you can execute bash scripts with make, but as others stated there are probably betterways